# Filter range by selecting any single word from a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google spreadsheets and trying to implement function in following way:

```
=FILTER(C3:C7,D3:D7=E3)
```

E3 contain words: "Where India Love Cannot"

Range D3:D7 : Each cell of range contain many words & no cell perfectly matches with E3, however few cells contain at least one word matching with any one word of E3.

Indeed I want to filter all those cells which contain any single word matching with any single word of E3.

Please help in correcting above formula, thanks in advance.

For more clarity visit following page:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5BJDLdzLJ_28Q2i3KR3ZTo76hDpK1-DLSq8rEBcELU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=FILTER(C3:C7,regexmatch(D3:D7, "(?i)"&substitute(E3, " ","|")))
```

and see if that works ? The "(?i)" makes it case-insensitive. You can leave it out if that is not needed.

Comment: You have made me your fan, thanks you are such genius